# Why does my C++ vector use a null pointer when I do not deference the pointer.

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I am working on a c++ object orientation project. I defined a vector as a private variable in my ListOfShapes class:

```
    vector<Shape*> list_of_shapes = {};
```

Shape is another class, and below is the header file of it:

```
class Shape{
private:
    string color;//private variable
public:
    Shape(string c);//non-default constructor
    string getColor();//returns color of the object
    virtual void print() = 0;//pure virtual "print" function
};
```

Shape is the parent class of a class called Rectangle:

```
class Rectangle:public Shape{
public:
    Rectangle(const string &c,double length,double breadth);
    void print();
private:
    double length, breadth;

};
```

In the main function I create a ListOfShapes object which contains a function that pushes a pointer (pointing to a Shape object) into the vector I mentioned above. Here is the implementation of the called function:

```
void ListOfShapes::addShape(Shape* s) {
    list_of_shapes.push_back(s); 
}
```

And finally here is the action of calling in the main function:

```
int main() {
    ListOfShapes* list;
    Shape* r;
    r = new Rectangle( "red",1,1);
    list->addShape( r);
    return 0;
}
```

My code compiles fine and even runs if I try to create the same vector (that stores pointers to Shape) inside the main function. The issue happens inside the addShape method, when the push_back method inside the vector class is called, it is using a null pointer for some reason. I've spent hours trying to debbug this issue but I cant seem to find the cause of it.
The error I am getting is:

[image: Debugger output]

Comment: `list->addShape( r);` -- Where does `list` point to?  And why not simply `ListOfShapes list;`?

Comment: *My code compiles fine and even runs* -- "Compiling fine" only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have realized from the start. Problem solved

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have another question regarding the same program if you dont mind. Say I want to place the line:
Shape* r;
    r = new Rectangle( "red",1,1);
inside a function. I know the pointer Shape* would get destroyed after the function is executed. Do you have any suggestions to go about it without creating another global array of pointers in the main

Comment: No, the object will not be destroyed.  Since you are using `new` (which is another issue, but that's besides the point), the object will continue to live until you call `delete`.

Comment: Thanks again! I will definitely look into all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing an uninitialized pointer `list`:

```
int main() {
    ListOfShapes* list;
    Shape* r;
    r = new Rectangle( "red",1,1);
    list->addShape( r);  // <-- list is not initialized, thus undefined behavior
    return 0;
}
```

If you look at your debugger output, you see that `this` has a strange value in the `addShape` function.  This is an indication that the object itself is not valid, and anything done within an invalid object is also invalid.

Simply create a `list` local object.  There is no need for a pointer:

```
int main() {
    ListOfShapes list;
    Shape* r;
    r = new Rectangle( "red",1,1);
    list.addShape( r);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, your `Shape` class should have a virtual destructor.  If you attempted to `delete` the objects stored in `list` by iterating through `list`, the program will invoke undefined behavior due to `Shape` not having a virtual destructor.